# How to pass the variable to the sql query in the python?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am trying to pass the input arguments to the AWS SQL Load command, but I am getting a wrong SQL syntax error. Can someone plz tell me where am I making a mistake?

```
tableName = sys.argv[1]
fileName = sys.argv[2]

curr.execute("""
    LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3-region://example-bkt/(%s)'
    INTO TABLE test_schema.(%s);""", (fileName,tableName))
```

This is the error which I am getting:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TEST_FILE')'
```

Comment: That is the typical way, however, the spots that you want to interpolate are not parameters. You will need to use standard string formatting in this case.

Comment: Is it just that is does not like the syntax using `test_schema.(%s)` with `()` around the table name? So try `test_schema.%s` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is not properly formatted. Try one of these options (second option is python3's improved string formatting):

```
command = "LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3-region://example-bkt/%s' INTO TABLE test_schema.%s;" % (fileName,tableName)

command = f"LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3-region://example-bkt/{fileName}' INTO TABLE test_schema.{tableName};"
```